# System (pid 4) process locks appdata

Tags: desktop-bridge

1. Convert win32 desktop app using `Desktop App Converter`.
2. Install app using generated appx.
3. Launch it and exit.
4. Not always, but very often, a strange thing happens: I can't modify/remove files from my original (non converted) app's %localappdata% folder. Files are in use by System (pid: 4) process. I have to uninstall appx to remove the lock.

Is it a bug?

Is there a workaround that does not require uninstalltion of Appx?

Why does it lock these files at all? As far as I know - converted app must use its own copy of %localappdata%.

Comment: What version of Windows are you testing on?

Comment: Windows 10, 1703 Build 15063.483

Comment: We had a bug similar to this, not sure if the fix has gone out to servicing yet. Can you clarify/share a complete repro for your issue? Thx!